# extract string between two dots

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string of the following format:

```
word1.word2.word3
```

What are the ways to extract *word2* from that string in perl?
I tried the following expression but it assigns 1 to *sub*:

```
@perleval $vars{sub} = $vars{string} =~ /.(.*)./; 0@
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried several suggestions, but still get the value of 1. I suspect that the entire expression above has a problem in addition to parsing. However, when I do simple assignment, I get the correct result:

```
@perleval $vars{sub} = $vars{string} ; 0@
```

assigns *word1.word2.word3* to variable *sub*

Comment: Try:

/\.([^.]+)\./  escaping the . and making what you want a negative character class

Comment: https://ideone.com/8EtVzb

Comment: You can also `split` the string and then select the `n` word from the resulting  list.

Comment: `$vars{string} =~ /.(.*)./;` looks like it returns 1 or 0 (true/false) depending on if the regex matched. You need a list context to get wantarray to kick in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
/\.([^\.]+)\./
```

. has a special meaning and would need to be escaped.  Then you would want to capture the values between the dots, so use a negative character class like ([^\.]+) meaning at least one non-dot.  if you use (.*) you will get:

word1.stuff1.stuff2.stuff3.word2 to result in:

```
stuff1.stuff2.stuff3
```

But maybe you want that?

Here is my little example, I do find the perl one liners a little harder to read at times so I break it out:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

if ("stuff1.stuff2.stuff3" =~ m/\.([^.]+)\./) {
    my $value = $1;
    print $value;
}
else {
    print "no match";
}
```

result

```
stuff2
```

Answer (score 5):

- `.` has a special meaning in regular expressions, so it needs to be escaped.
- `.*` could match more than intended. `[^.]*` is safer.
- The match operator (`//`) simply returns true/false in scalar context.

You can use any of the following:

```
$vars{sub} = $vars{string} =~ /\.([^.]*)\./ ? $1 : undef;
```

```
$vars{sub} = ( $vars{string} =~ /\.([^.]*)\./ )[0];
```

```
( $vars{sub} ) = $vars{string} =~ /\.([^.]*)\./;
```

The first one allows you to provide a default if there's no match.

Answer (score 3):

`.` has a special meaning: any character (see the expression between your parentheses)

Therefore you have to escape it (`\.`) if you search a *literal* dot:

`/\.(.*)\./`

Comment: The answer from sniperd works for me, too. Unclear why you get "1"

Answer (score 0):

You've got to make sure you're asking for a list when you do the search.

```
my $x= $string =~ /look for (pattern)/ ;
```

sets `$x` to 1

```
my ($x)= $string =~ /look for (pattern)/ ;
```

sets `$x` to pattern.